# Ngrx store manage multiple lists of objects

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I'm developing Angular 2 application together with `ngrx`. I have several questions of how implement store based on my current project requirements.

To be more specific let's say I have two list of users on my website. The first list contains `Active users` and another list contains the `Best contributors`. All objects inside both list are type of `User` which is defined by:

```
export interface User {
    id: string
    firstName: string,
    lastName, string
    email: string
}
```

There are several ways to implement these two lists inside the store. I have 3 possible ways to do it, but I would like to hear how are other people doing it.

## Approach 1

In this case every angular component, in this case `Active users` and `Top contributors` will have its own object inside the store, together with belonging reducers, effects etc.

```
activeUsers: [
    {
        id: 1
        firstName: "User 1"
        lastName: "Lastname 1"
        email: "user1@example.com"
    },
    {
        id: 2
        firstName: "User 2"
        lastName: "Lastname 2"
        email: "user2@example.com"
    },

]


 topContributors: [
    {
        id: 1
        firstName: "User 1"
        lastName: "Lastname 1"
        email: "user1@example.com"
    },
    {
        id: 5
        firstName: "User 5"
        lastName: "Lastname 5"
        email: "user5@example.com"
    },

]
```

Having separated store objects for separated lists will give me a benefit to have really simple reducers so I can easily add/remove/update data, but there is now another problem. For example `User 1` is in both lists and I have to update this object on two places which is adding really similar logic on 2 places. Ideally would be to have one reducer that can handle both lists which leads me to approach 2.

## Approach 2

In this case store will contain top `user` object which then contains array of users separated by list name. Here is an example:

```
users: [
    activeUsers: [
    {
        id: 1
        firstName: "User 1"
        lastName: "Lastname 1"
        email: "user1@example.com"
    },
    {
        id: 2
        firstName: "User 2"
        lastName: "Lastname 2"
        email: "user2@example.com"
    },

]


 topContributors: [
    {
        id: 1
        firstName: "User 1"
        lastName: "Lastname 1"
        email: "user1@example.com"
    },
    {
        id: 5
        firstName: "User 5"
        lastName: "Lastname 5"
        email: "user5@example.com"
    },

    ]   
]
```

In this case, reducers will be a bit more complex (because they have to handle specific list based on the list name), but enough general to add/remove/update any list I have. Again, in this case, I have to go through all lists and find user I want to let's say edit and edit it multiple times. Please note that in this case every list has to be uniquely identified by name like in my case: `activeUsers`, `topContributors`. This gives me great ability to create selectors that will return me desired list:

```
this.store.select(userList("activeUsers")).subscribe()
```

Things could be more complex if we start adding more nested data, but I will try to avoid that.

## Approach 3

Redux pattern is suggesting to have so called tables in the store. That means I will have a table called users where I will store all user objects. Let's say I have two API calls. One will fetch active users and another api call will fetch top contributors. At which moment I have to merge these two sources so I have table of users in the store with no duplicated entry (for example user 1 can be in both lists)?

## Question

How do you handle store (how you design it) when you manage multiple lists of the same objects on your website?

Comment: What defines `top contributors` or `active users`? IMO easiest way to manage these stores is to normalized your data on your store, then you can use selectors to filter. So in this case what I would do is you have a list of `users` and property `isActive` and `isTopContributor` or something similar... You then have a selectors `getActiveUsers()` and `getTopContributors()` for example. Simple, and you only call the db once to retrieve the users and let the client side handle the filtering

Comment: This approach requires me to put users of both lists into same store table and add flag to every user object so I can use selectors. There is another problem if the user is on both lists then I have to add both flags. This becomes more complicated if I have 3,4 or 5 similar lists.

Comment: No, what I described is basically "Approach 3". You wouldn't have duplicated users under your users store. Think of it as "Users" is like your table from the database where you only have a unique users. Then your selectors is basically "Queries" just like how you would do in database SELECT statements.

Comment: It is not problem having normalised state but let's say I have list of 50 users in my normalised store. How can I identify which from those 50 are top contributors and which are the most active users?

Comment: Well, what defines top contributors or active users?

Comment: Let's say I have one API endpoint to get me top contributors and another API endpoint that returns active users. Both are defined by user type.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment that you have to update both lists, my advise would be to manage users and contributors as one entity in the store.

To distinguish both types of users, keep a separated list with a reference to the user's table:

```
{
   users: {...},
   activeUsers: [10, 23, 6],
   topContributors: [9, 10, 33]
}
```